# Check if a user exists in SQL database, make the user, if not, don't make one?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I was wondering how to check if a user exists, and if the user does exist, tell them their account is already in use? Thanks!

EDIT: Kind of like a COLUMN_EXISTS type function?
EDIT: It's a MySQL Server! :D

Comment: [What did you try](http://whatdidyoutry.com)?

Comment: You need to specify the RDBMS in order to get a helpful answer ( Oracle? MySQL? SQL-Server? ) etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to issue a statement

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE login="JohnSmith"
```

and see if it gives you any rows. If yes - user exists.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I used: if (isset($row['EMAIL'])) { echo "Your email is already in use. Try again."; } else { //Write to the MySQL DB. } Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'SnarkyDTheman')
THEN
INSERT INTO USERS ...

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your SQL dialect.  Even something like this isn't portable:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username)
    INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (@username);
ELSE
    RAISERROR 'whatever';
```

Have a look at [the MySQL documentation for the IF statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if-statement.html).

With MySQL your options for raising an error are a little convoluted.  You could return a rowset from the stored program which indicates whether an insert was performed or not.